# Получить массив определенного вида PHP

Tags: php, массивы, консоль

Использую API Random.ORG с движком с github: LoLFactor\RandomORG\

php код:

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
use LoLFactor\RandomORG\RandomORGClient;
$client = new RandomORGClient('5035-35353-53535-53535-3535');

$data = $client->generateSignedIntegers(1, 1, 60);
$i = 0;
$arr = array();
foreach($data as $randomInt) {
    array_push($arr, ($randomInt));
}
echo '<br>';
var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

Получаю массив такого вида:

```
"["2.0",{"random":{"method":"generateSignedIntegers","hashedApiKey":"FZSXJR+2P+umSj1UIOvBEc3RpYuwh8ZQfqppk8O5froIsgTlcPWRmoYkKzLB07cCs4TXgMcZS+MduDyF0RK9+Q==","n":1,"min":1,"max":60,"replacement":true,"base":10,"data":[48],"completionTime":"2015-10-03 11:52:32Z","serialNumber":276},"signature":"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","bitsUsed":6,"bitsLeft":248458,"requestsLeft":742,"advisoryDelay":0},"G5nucL0Wdy9xtbejw"]"
```

В консоли браузера выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужен массив такого вида:

```
"{"random":{"method":"generateSignedIntegers","hashedApiKey":"FZSXJR+2P+umSj1UIOvBEc3RpYuwh8ZQfqppk8O5froIsgTlcPWRmoYkKzLB07cCs4TXgMcZS+MduDyF0RK9+Q==","n":1,"min":1,"max":60,"replacement":true,"base":10,"data":[48],"completionTime":"2015-10-03 11:52:32Z","serialNumber":276},"signature":"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","bitsUsed":6,"bitsLeft":248458,"requestsLeft":742,"advisoryDelay":0}"
```

И тогда в браузере будет выглядеть правильно, вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отличие этих 2х массивов в том, что код `["2.0",` и код `,"G5nucL0Wdy9xtbejw"]` отсутствует вначале и в конце массива, который мне нужен.
Как мне удалить это первое и последнее значение из массива?
Или как преобразовать его в такой вид, как я хочу?
Пробовал array_merge, array_split пока ничего не придумал.

Надеюсь не сильно запутал суть вопроса. Спасибо.

Comment: `var_dump(json_encode($arr[1])); ` ?

Comment: @Visman , огромное спасибо. Получился верный код, правда в консоли встало все не так, как я ожидал. http://i.shotnes.com/a/03/vkeuuaox.ebr_560fcd8e1a414.png Ну ничего, сейчас буду разбираться..